# Oracle APEX 5.0 cannot change title

Tags: oracle-apex

I am completely new in Oracle APEX. I cannot understand why it is not possible to change the page title. It can be set while creating a new app using the wizard, but after finishing the process of creating the new application it is not possible to change existing page title.

Is there a way to change the page title after creating the app?

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible:

[image]

In close-up:

[image]